# Как реализовать удаление всех элементов со значением в hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

Не получается реализовать функцию удаления. Подаётся значение, все элементы с этим значением должны быть удалены, что я делаю не так?

```
package Project;

import java.util.*;

public class ReallyNewHashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V> {
    private HashMapper[] table;
    private final int INITIAL_CAPASITY = 75;
    private int capacity;
    private double loadfactor;
    private double treshold;
    private int lenght;

    public ReallyNewHashMap() {
        loadfactor = 0.75;
        capacity = INITIAL_CAPASITY;
        table = new HashMapper[INITIAL_CAPASITY];
        treshold = INITIAL_CAPASITY * loadfactor;

    }
    public void insert(K key,V value){
        int hs =hash(key.hashCode()); // вычисляем хэш-код значения в таблице
        int idx = indexFor(key.hashCode(),capacity); //вычисляем индекс Ноды в таблице
        HashMapper e = new HashMapper(hs,key,value,null); // создаем ноду
        if(table[idx] == null){
            table[idx] = e;
            lenght+=1;
            refresh();
        }else{
            HashMapper temp  = table[idx];
            while(temp!=null){
                if(e.hash== temp.hash &&(e.key == temp.key||(e.key).equals(temp.key) )){ /// ситуация если ключи не совпадают а хэши совпадают обработана здесь
                    temp.value = e.value;

                    return;
                }
                if(temp.next==null){
                    break;
                }
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            temp.next = e;
            refresh();
        }
    }



    public void delete(V value){
        for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
            if (table[i] != null) {
                if(table[i].next==null){
                    if(table[i].value.equals((V)value)) {
                        table[i] = null;
                        continue;
                    }

                }
                HashMapper temp = table[i];
                while (temp != null && temp.next != null ) {
                        while (  temp.next!=null &&  temp.next.value.equals((V) value)){
                            if(temp.next.next==null){
                                temp.next = null;
                                continue;

                            }
                            temp.next = temp.next.next;
                        }

                   if(temp.next!=null) {

                       temp = temp.next;
                   }




                }



            }
        }
    }

    private  static int indexFor(int h, int length)   //h = key.hashCode() lenght = capacity
    {
        return h & (length - 1);
    }


     private  static int hash(int h)
    {
        h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
        return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
    }    



    private class HashMapper<K, V> implements Map.Entry<K, V> {
          private   int hash;
          private final K key;
          private   V value;
          private HashMapper<K, V> next;

        HashMapper(int hash, K key, V value, HashMapper<K, V> next) {
            this.hash = hash;
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }


        public final K getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public final V getValue() {
            return value;
        }
        public final int hashCode() {
            hash = 31;
            hash = hash * 17 + key.hashCode();
            return hash;
        }

        public final V setValue(V newValue) {
            V oldValue = value;
            value = newValue;
            return oldValue;
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: Оставьте только тот код, который относится к вашему вопросу.

Comment: Изменил,оставил

Comment: `что я делаю не так?` не заставляйте нас угадывать вашу ошибку, прямо пишите что конкретно у вас не работает, какая у вас ошибка или что конкретно не получается.

Comment: Я бы выделил удаление из связанного списка в отдельную функцию и протестировал бы ее вдоль и поперек.